# Corrupted ZipArchive after setContent() in php symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, zip, corrupt

I have a real strange behavior when sending a zip archive containing a any type of file in symfony.
The problem is that the zip file, that I download from the browser contains an extra 'bit' at the beginning of the file.

Here's my code:

```
$tmpFileName = tempnam("/tmp", "xb_");
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($tmpFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE);
$zip->addFile('[directory_inside_webspace]/test.pdf', 'myTest.pdf');
$zip->close();
$this->getResponse()->clearHttpHeaders();
$this->getResponse()->setContent(file_get_contents($tmpFileName));
$this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
$this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=archive.zip');
return sfView::NONE;
```

Now here's what is strange. The temporary zip file under /tmp is fine. I can extract it without any problems.
But the file the browser sends to me is corrupt. When I open both of them in hex editor, the first few bytes look like:

```
working file:      50 4B 03 04 14 00 00 
corrupt file:   0A 50 4B 03 04 14 00 00
```

When I remove the addition '0A' from the corrupt file I can open it without problems.
It's now the exactly same file as the tmp file created in /tmp.

Did anyone had a behavior like this before?? I'm stucked at this problem for over 4 days now and I'm not able to find the error.
I use exactly the same code in another symfony module and it's working in there. Any ideas ?

-----Update------

The problem wasn't related to the zipArchive or setContent.
I had a query at the beginning of the function.

```
$bill = Doctrine::getTable('Bill')->find($request->getParameter('id'));
```

In the class 'Bill.class.php' in my doctrine model I had a blank line before

```
<?php
```

So when the class Bill was instantiated the new line was print to screen.

I just wonder why php doesn't give an error message like 'headers already send' when sending the zip Archive to the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0A` is a newline character. Make sure there's no newline before the `<?php` tag of all the files involved, and no newline after the `?>` tag (unless you omit the closing tag, which is recommended).
The most probable culprit is the actions.class.php of the download action.

Comment: Thanks so much, this was my problem!

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem in symfony a few days ago and the issue for me was there was an extra character (a space in my instance) sneaking into my response. Instead of return sfView::NONE; what happense if you add a die at the end? Try this:

```
//make sure toolbar is disabled just to be extra safe
sfConfig::set('sf_web_debug', false);

$tmpFileName = tempnam("/tmp", "xb_");
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($tmpFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE);
$zip->addFile('[directory_inside_webspace]/test.pdf', 'myTest.pdf');
$zip->close();

$this->getResponse()->clearHttpHeaders();
$this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
$this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=archive.zip');

// Unlock session in order to prevent php session warnings
$this->getUser()->shutdown();

// Send http headers to user client
$this->getResponse()->sendHttpHeaders();

echo file_get_contents($tmpFileName);

die;
```

Comment: Instead of echo, you should readfile(); and return sfView::HEADER_ONLY;. And don't forgot to put session_write_close(); if you don't want to block your user on that download action (PHP lock the users sessions).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately the produced zip archive is still corrupt. With the same additional bit at the beginning. :(

Comment: What is the output if you do everything EXCEPT outputting the file contents? Are there any bytes sneaking into the response? Also what happens if you do an md5_file of the archive that's generated verses the good version of the zip - do they match?

Comment: @Dan Good idea. After removing the file contents I get a zip file that contains exactly '0A'. The thing that messes up the file.
The md5_file hashes do not match! It's getting even stranger!

Comment: 0A is a line feed character. Somehow a \n is being added.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it:

```
// Unlock php session
$this->getUser()->shutdown();

// Send the response
$response->sendHttpHeaders();
$response->setContent(readfile(utf8_decode($tmpFileName)));
$response->sendContent();

return sfView::NONE;
```

It's probably a [BOM error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: Thanks but this gives me exactly the same error. I'm lost in confusion.